# wso2 IS 520 user accountDisabled claim verify as 'admin'

Tags: java, ldap, wso2, ldap-query, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to verify a multi-tenant environment **USER** account is enabled or disabled using WS ?

```
getUserClaimValue
```

IS the only one I could see !, unfortunately it asks for User credentials !
Cant we do it at admin level ?

Its not even storing into ldap-attributes. How can I get this verified as *super-admin*.

**Claim URI** :

> http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled

Worked out to get the claim as 'ref'.
How to get the **value** from this 'ref' direct using LDAP with JAVA ?

Answer (score 1):

Any claims which has the pattern `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/XXXXX` is considered as a special claim. Hence they are ignored by `getUserClaimValue` (and by `setUserClaimValue` when setting value).

You'll need to use either `getUserClaimValues` or `getUserClaimValuesForClaims` for the above purpose (And `setUserClaimValues` to set).

**Update**

Due to the tenant separation model it is not allowed to get claim details by other tenant admins (Even for super tenant admin). In case you really need that, one possible option would be to write a custom admin service extending the `org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.UserStoreManagerService` class (which reflects `RemoteUserStoreManagerService`) where it will [start a tenant flow for the user's tenant](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/CarbonContext+API#CarbonContextAPI-Switchingtenantflows), and call super class method to get the claim value.

Comment: Both the get's are useful when we have tenant 'admin' credentials, cant we get the values with super-tenant credentials, its currently throwing User-NotFound as SOAPFault.

Comment: I didn't notice the super-tenant credentials part. Updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: is there any samples that you can provide for reference !

Comment: receiving exception. java.lang.RuntimeException: A queue manager instance has already been set. & Unable to read Server Configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException